# Implicit Differentiation with a Tangent Line

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I was looking to implicitly differentiate $$-22x^6+4x^{33}y+y^7=-17$$
and found it to be $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{132x^5-132x^{32}y}{4x^{33}+7y^6}$$Now, I am trying to find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the coordinate (1,1). So I then plug both 1 in for x and y into the above equation and come up with $$\dfrac{0}{11}$$Now I go to solve $$y-y1=m(x-x1)$$ getting $$y-1=0(x-1)$$
resulting in $y=1$ and the equation to be $y=x+1$ for my final answer. Am I going about this in the correct manner?

Comment: You start with $-22x^6 + 4x^{33}y + y^7 = -17$. Then you take (implicit) derivatives. What you wrote isn't that, and is not what you mean. What you wrote is that you started with the differential equation $y'-22x^6+4x^{33}y + y^7 = -17$.

Comment: I follow your work to get $y=1$  why do you say $y =x+1$?  You have shown that the slope is $0$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is fine but since $m=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)_{(1,1)}=0$ we have

$$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)=0 \implies y=1$$

Comment: You're right! I for some reason thought we had to maintain the x for the sake of the equation. Thank you.

Comment: @pijoborde You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

your calculations for the slope of tangent are correct. The only point that you have missed is the last step of finding the equation of tangent line which is simply $y=1$ not $y=x+1$

Comment: That's exactly the point!